# Pseudo line between list elements?

Tags: css

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2ffn3yth/)

I'm trying to create a layout like:

```
One

--

Two

--

Three
```

The layout has pseudo lines between each of the list elements.

```
<ul>
 <li>One</li>
 <li>Two</li>
 <li>Three</li>
 <li>Four</li>
```

From the fiddle I can get in the line, just having trouble positioning it equally between the list elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the margin from the list-item (`li`), make it's pseudo element block-level, remove absolute positioning, and give it some margin.

Here you go: [[fiddle]](https://jsfiddle.net/2ffn3yth/2/)

```css
ul{
  list-style-type: none;
}
li{
  position: relative;
}
li:not(:last-child):after{
  content:"";
  display: block;
  margin: 3em 0;
  border-bottom: 3px solid blue;
  width: 30px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li>One</li>
<li>Two</li>
<li>Three</li>
<li>Four</li>
</ul>
```

EDIT: As advised by Drew Kennedy in the comment to this answer, I edited it and made it look more perfect on the requirement of OP.

Comment: Judging by the requirement of the OP, I don't think he or she wants a line after the final list item. You can change your pseudo element to `li:not(:last-child):after` and it will work as intended.

Comment: Just edited the answer to make it look better. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Great, anyway to make the pseudo elements centered?

Comment: Make it `margin: 3em auto` for the pseudo element, and you are good to go.

Answer (score 1):

This only gives you lines between the elements, not adding one to the last.

```
ul > li:not(:last-child):after {
 content:"";
  border-bottom: 3px solid blue;
  position: absolute;
  top: -15px; /* your top padding */
  left: 0;
  width: 30px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add left and bottom properties [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RACCH/t7q58662/)

```
li:after {
    content: "";
    border-bottom: 3px solid blue;
    position: absolute;
    width: 30px;
    bottom: -25px;
    left: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/h6ffn6L0/

```
ul{
  list-style-type: none;
}
li{
padding-bottom:30px;
position: relative;
}
li:after{
  content:"";
  border-bottom: 3px solid blue;
  position: absolute;
  top: -15px; /* your top padding */
  left: 0;
  width: 30px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `left` and `bottom` properties to your pseudo elements to position them relative to your `li`.

This should help you:

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

li {
  margin: 3em 0;
  position: relative;
}

li:after {
  content: "";
  border-bottom: 3px solid blue;
  position: absolute;
  width: 30px;
  bottom: -20px;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
  <li>Four</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using `li:after` for the border?
Just add the Border to the li Element:

```
li {
    border-bottom: 3px solid blue;
}
```

You can use padding and/or margin for the space between the Borders.

Answer (score 0):

If you set li:after to display: block, you can change it margins to position it a certain distance from the list item.

```css
ul{
  list-style-type: none;
}
li{
  position: relative;
  margin-top:50px;
}
li:after{
  content:"";
  margin-top: 25px;
  border-bottom: 3px solid blue;
  width: 30px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li>One</li>
<li>Two</li>
<li>Three</li>
<li>Four</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need limited width borders between list items, I would suggest you to use `linear-gradinet()` to draw them as background image.

Below is a working example:

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
li {
  padding: 1.5em 0;
}
li:not(:last-child) {
  background: linear-gradient(blue, blue) no-repeat;
  background-position: left bottom;
  background-size: 30px 3px; /* First value represents width
                                while second represents height of border */
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
  <li>Four</li>
</ul>
```